# Changing color of a rich text box and adding text to it when pressing enter

Tags: c#

I'm making an RPG-style text-based game. Currently it is in a Console Application, but I would rather move it to a Windows Form Application, for some added features and fanciness. This brings up a few issues.

Colors differentiate the types of messages, so color is important. I found this on another question:

```
int length = richTextBox.TextLength;  // at end of text
richTextBox.AppendText(mystring);
richTextBox.SelectionStart = length;
richTextBox.SelectionLength = mystring.Length;
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

This seems to add the color after the text. Is there a better way to go about colors? Also, what if I want multiple different colors on one line? That complicates things. (It would be best if I could use color codes to designate the colors in the strings themselves, something like &&4this is red &&fthis is white &&0this is black, but I suppose that might just over-complicate things.)

Currently, the input box is a simple text box. When you press enter, nothing happens. I want enter to clear the text box and output a string that I can work with (not necessarily add to the rich text box).

Comment: Been a while since I've tried.. but I'm pretty sure you can set the `SelectionColor` before appending text and it will take on that color. Then you just switch it back afterwards..

Comment: @rae1n He has provided something he has tried.. and even appears to have debugged his issue.. what more do you want?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead It seems the code he presented wasn't his.

Comment: Clearly it is not. That's not really relevant.

Answer (score 3):

What I assumed in my comment is true, just tested it. Change your code to this:

```
Color prevColor = richTextBox.SelectionColor;
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox.AppendText(mystring);
richTextBox.SelectionColor = prevColor;
```

Comment: I'll check that out when I get a chance. Do you know what I can do about activating the input box on [Enter]?

Comment: That is tutorial #4 on every WinForms tutorial. I suggest a search :)

Comment: A straight answer would be the most helpful. :/

Comment: We are in the business of making sure people dont just receive answers but also learn. Otherwise we might end up working with you one day.. and you dont know the trade :) Besides, theres 600+ answers here that answer that specific question.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know what to search for.